# Related categories and subCategories with product count

Tags: php, sql, categories

Im looking to create a ul list of categories and its sub categories (with count) related to the users search.

Example.
if you was to go to ebay and search mac book pro, on the left it would show

```
Computers/Tablets & Networking (20 items)
   -Laptop & Desktop Accessories (5 items)
   -Laptops & Netbooks (15 items)
```

I have 2 tables:

```
Categories Table

id  |  category_name  |  parent_id
--------------------------------------
1   | computers       |     0
2   | apple           |     2
3   | microsoft       |     2
4   | accessories     |     0
5   | mouse           |     4
6   | keyboards       |     4
7   | printers        |     4

#############################################################

And Products Table

id  |  product_name  |  category_id
--------------------------------------
1   | macbook pro      |     2
2   | macbook air      |     2
3   | surface pro      |     3
4   | ipad             |     2
5   | backlit keyboard |     6
6   | mini keyboard    |     6
7   | 3 in 1 printer   |     7


some sql and php to disply:

computers (4)
  -apple (3)
  -microsoft (1)

accessories (3)
  -keyboards (2)
  -printers (1)
  -(dont show mouse because no mouses in products table)
```

I have spent the last few hours searching but havent found what im looking for.

Regards
Shane

Comment: What database are you using?  Does your category hierarchy run more than 1 level deep?

Comment: im using mysql and no just main categories and its related subcategories. thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get what you want just using `with rollup`.  The problem is that the sum will appear after the base rows:

```
  select cp.category_name as parent_name, c.category_name, count(*) as numcategories
  from products p join
       categories c
       on p.categoryid = c.id join
       categories cp
       on c.parentid = cp.id
  group by cp.category_name, c.category_name with rollup
```

To get it before, try this:

```
select parent_name, category_name, numcategories
from (select cp.category_name as parent_name, c.category_name, count(*) as numcategories
      from products p join
           categories c
           on p.categoryid = c.id join
           categories cp
           on c.parentid = cp.id
      group by cp.category_name, c.category_name with rollup
     ) t
where category_name is not null
order by category_name,
         category_name is null desc;
```

Comment: I cant seem to get theses working, but wouldnt I have to have to loops/sqls one for the main category and counter, then the secound loop for the subcategories and counter.

Comment: @Shane . . . You shouldn't have to do that.  How are these not working?  Syntax error?  Wrong results?

Comment: please see post below

Comment: @Shane . . . Fix the table aliases, as per my last edit.

Comment: @Gordon... I just updated my last post with new aliases and some modifications of my own. please advise. Regards

Comment: @Gordon... time for that cigar... thanks for your help mate regards

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon Linoff using the second statment:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,"select parent_name, category_name, counter from (select cp.category_name as parent_name, c.category_name, count(*) as counter from adverts p join categories c on p.category_id = c.id join categories cp on c.parent_id = cp.id group by cp.category_name, c.category_name with rollup) t where category_name is not null order by parent_name, counter DESC");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count >= 1){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

     if (empty($rowo['category_name'])) {

         $category_view = ("<strong>". $rowo['parent_name']. "</strong> (". $rowo['counter']. ")"); 

     }else{

        $category_view = ("". $rowo['category_name']. " (". $rowo['counter']. ")");

     }


     echo("<li>". $category_view ."</li>");


   } // while loop

}  // counter >= 1




Antiques (3)  
   -Fabric/ Textiles (2)  
   -Ethnographic Antiques (1)
Art (5)  
   -Photographs (4)  
   -Drawings (1)
```

Thanks again Gordon.

Comment: not to push my luck but maybe art first because counter is greater then antiques.